# QGIS: Burning stream network (catchment area)

Tags: qgis, dem, hydrology, stream

I need help from stackexchange because of a DEM correction problem...

I have a DEM with a 5 meters resolution where one of the main river is cut by a large highway. In order to delete that topology error I'm looking for a method for burning the river in the DEM.

After looking at tutorials I've tried "r.carve" (additionnal stream depth = 10 meters) but even thought it happened to have corrected my DEM, the flow accumulation in this area is very discontinuous...

What is the problem here?

[image: r.carve]

[image: cathment area]

Comment: I find looking at your DEM in hillshade mode can help to see if the carve function worked. I usually just use fill sinks because it doesn't really matter in my analysis but it looks like there is a SAGA alg called Sink Removal that may do what you want as an alternative to r.carve.

Comment: @Baswein: I used the fill sinks function before running "r.carve" but actually I should have done it after ! I completely forgot that I had to renew that process after having modified my DEM ! 
Thank you for the hint !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I would rather use `Fill sinks (Wang & Lui)` after using `r.carve` !

Make also sure that your vector and raster layers have the same projection.

http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.1.3/ta_preprocessor_4.html